# Save Save datepicker range in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, datepicker

i'm using datatable with date range filter by using datepicker.
When i set
stateSave: true

it saves all values except the range set into the input datepicker field.
Any help on this?

Have a look here:
http://live.datatables.net/kajabeli/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has documented custom filters
https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

That will filters age (similiar cases with yours)

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var start_date = Date.parse($('#start_date').val()) / 1000 || 0;
        var end_date = Date.parse($('#end_date').val()) / 1000 || 0;
        var value = Date.parse(data[5]) / 1000 || 0;
        /* put your filter conditions here,  */
        if ( ( start_date && end_date ) ||
            ( start_date && value <= end_date ) ||
            ( start_date <= value && end_date ) ||
            ( start_date <= value && value <= end_date ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Add below codes after your dataTable initiation.

```
$('#start_date, #start_date').change( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't save the value. What i need is to save (local session browser) the start date and the end date that is set with the datepicker...

Comment: Just check my updated answer, you could do like that based on documentation

Comment: thanks again, to implement your code into http://live.datatables.net/kajabeli/2/edit ?

Comment: the problem is that the value into the datepicker is not saved... like for exampe as for  the search input box

Comment: something wrong on datatables live, you should try in your local http://live.datatables.net/kajabeli/10/ (updated)

Comment: because it works in here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNooow (just add jquery by clicking the gear icon of js)

Comment: unfortunally it doesn't save the datepicker value. Try to refresh the page... the datepicker  is reinitialized... so doesn't save the value set.